# Javascript code for rotating remarks. Not sure how to ask

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Example is in the header](http://www.tylerbuilds.co/)

I've been trying to do something like the header of this portfolio for a while. Where you can get different remarks on the same line by clicking the arrow. It also doesn't refresh anything which is neat. I just dont know to how phrase the question. I finally found this example. Can anyone help me with the JS or jQuery code? Sorry if this has been answered before I've tried phrasing it so many different ways but can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Code hidden behind a link to your site is not the right way to ask. Please post the relevant parts of that code in your question.

Comment: You should try and replicate it yourself first and post a question here if you have a specific issue with the code you've written.

Comment: take a look at the scripts.js file on said website

Comment: It's not my website obviously. Secondly i did look at JS code but since im still fairly new to JS and jQuery i couldn't pick out the parts that were specifically for the updating text and the one that were for the spinner animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Easy mode! [Here's a working demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naomi/wrkmH/)

Setup some html

```
<p>
    I'm a <span id="remark">Panda</span> bear.
    <button id="nextRemark">refresh</button>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cFadsAE.gif" id="spinner"/>
<p>
```

Write some JavaScript (with jQuery)

```
$(function(){
    var remarks = ["Koala", "Kangaroo", "Circus", "Grizzly"],
        spinner = $("#spinner"),
        delay   = 1000;

    $("#nextRemark").click(function(event) {

        var button = $(this);

        // display spinner, hide button
        spinner.show();
        button.hide();

        setTimeout(function() {
            var r;

            // display remark
            if (r = remarks.pop()) {
                $("#remark").text(r);
            }

            // no more remarks
            else {
                $("#remark").text("dead");
                button.remove();
            }

            // hide spinner, show button
            spinner.hide();
            button.show();

        }, delay);

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

It doesn't have fancy animations or superfluous delays, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: I think he's actually a big fan of the rotating arrow and not just the updating of the text but I could be wrong ;-)

Comment: There, I added the goofy spinner.

Comment: I was actually going more for the updating text then the spinner animation. But both look great thank you! I was having trouble picking out the parts in his script.js that were for the text updates and which were for the spinner animation because im still fairly new to JS and jQuery. Edit: i know the comments show where one ends and the other starts but it wasn't working for me so i thought i was getting the wrong code.

Comment: If you don't want to see the spinner code, look at [revision #2](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4df9362e-7add-49a6-8832-776d79de39e5/view-source) of my post.